# iOS - react-native-beacons-manager - better battery saving possible?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i use the library 1.1.0 react-native-beacons-manager to spot beacons. The spotting takes place 3 times a second. This is not good for a battery. Anybody know how i can reduce the spotting for iOS? The function foreground and backgroundScanPeriod() is only possible for android. Is there a Solution or a fork?